# SD card freezes windows functions

Tags: windows-10, sd-card

I have an SD card that I was trying to access from my windows laptop. The SD card is most probably write protected as it came from an electronic dictionary. But most of the time when I try to access it it just freezes my whole system. DiskPart functions freeze up when I select the disk. I can't even format it without losing control to my laptop for 5 minutes. I most probably will throw the sd card away, but I want to know why this happens and how I can prevent it. It shouldn't be right that the whole system stops working when a weird external storage device is inserted.

Thanks in advance.

My device is a MSI PE70 6QE on Windows 10 64 bit with 12GB ram.

Comment: Maybe your virus protection insists on verifying the complete SD card before it allows other OS functions to access it? That could take a while. Try with virus protection deactivated. Or maybe the indexer runs a full index?

Comment: @Aganju I don't have any active running antiviruses or other protection. Even right clicking on it freezes up my file explorer.

Comment: Restart explorer after plugging that drive. You may also disable autoplay in settings. If SD card has not any data clean it with diskpart.